# How to Customize Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How to customize FrameLayout, I have to make screen like this:

[image]

and i have made this :

[image]

So now i want to know, `How can i achieve above Layout`

1. How to `show icon on top`, like in above screen (**Path**)
2. How to `place text above circles`, like in above screen (`Dark Text:` **Remember Life**) (`Light Text:` **Instantly ....**)
3. How to **place buttons below circles**, like in above screen (**Register** & **Login**)

Here is my `XML`, in which i am using `FrameLayout`, see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.indianic.viewflipperdemo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.indianic.viewflipperdemo.widget.ViewFlow
        android:id="@+id/viewflow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:sidebuffer="3" >
    </com.indianic.viewflipperdemo.widget.ViewFlow>

    <com.indianic.viewflipperdemo.widget.CircleFlowIndicator
        android:id="@+id/viewflowindic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        app:inactiveType="stroke" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Use relative layout, position labels and buttons as you want and set image as background of main container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I achieved my target, I used `both the Layouts` [`Relative Layout` and `Linear Layout`] to `organize widgets`, see complete **XML** :

**circle_layout.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.indianic.viewflipperdemo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <com.indianic.viewflipperdemo.widget.ViewFlow
        android:id="@+id/viewflow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:sidebuffer="3" >
    </com.indianic.viewflipperdemo.widget.ViewFlow>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Remember Life"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/viewflowindic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Instantly search memories of friends, season, birthdays, and more"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.indianic.viewflipperdemo.widget.CircleFlowIndicator
        android:id="@+id/viewflowindic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:inactiveType="stroke" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And look at this awesome `screenshot`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout instead FrameLayout. You will be more free with elements positions.

[Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Something like this you can do it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.indianic.viewflipperdemo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.indianic.viewflipperdemo.widget.ViewFlow
        android:id="@+id/viewflow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:sidebuffer="3" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <com.indianic.viewflipperdemo.widget.ViewFlow
        android:id="@+id/viewflowindic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_register"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        app:inactiveType="stroke" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/viewflowindic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="description"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/description"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="title"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

btw use match_parent instead fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use **RelativeLayout** to organize views. For implementing **view pager indicator** try this link

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Sample

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    //You can put an image view or text view to show your app name

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Path"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"/>

    **// Try view pager indicator here.**

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Register"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```